# Traefik - 404 page not found when use https

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I was trying to implement HTTPS over my traefik using self-signed certificate. Everything works fine through http, but when I try to use HTTPS I receive

```
404 page not found
```

I only want for now to have only dashboard over HTTPS and after that I'm going to implement it to other services.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.10
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $PWD/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - $PWD/dynamic-conf:/dynamic-conf
      - $PWD/ssl:/opt/certs

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
    external: true
```

Here is my traefik.yml (static traefik config) file:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
accessLog: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entrypoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https
  https:
    address: ":443"


providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file: 
    fileName: /dynamic-conf/traefik-dynamic.yml
```

And here is my traefik-dynamic.yml file:

```
http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      entryPoints:
        - http
        - https
      service: api@internal
      rule: "Host(`localhost`)"
      middlewares: http_to_https
  middlewares:
    http_to_https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /opt/certs/cert.crt
      keyFile: /opt/certs/cert.key
```

I'll just add that when I click padlock icon on my browser I get my certificate with proper value.

I tried, as you can see on the code above, to make redirections to proper entryPoint, but it also doesn't work.

PS. When I don't have set redirection to https, when I go to http://localhost:443/ it works fine, but https://localhost/ doesn't work.

I was thinking there is trouble with my browser, but it's not, because I was trying this URL on Firefox and Google Chrome with same effect.
Can somebody find wrong configuration in my file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, again after I posted here my problem I resolved this in short time. All I had to do was add line

```
tls: true
```

to traefik-dynamic.conf in dashboard router section. After that it works well.